# react-intl - date without day - just month/year

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

intl library and want to display the date with just month number and year seperated by /; just like this:

```
<FormattedDate value="05/2017" />
```

Can i format it in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just need to pass the formatter options to `<FormattedDate />` explicitly.

```
<FormattedDate
  value={new Date(2017, 5, 9)}
  month="2-digit"
  year="numeric"
/>
```

For more information about Date / Time formatting, see https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#date-formatting-components.

Comment: I saw this documentation but still dont see a way to forma it like this: "05/2017" where 05 is month

Comment: If this is not an answer to your question, then I don’t understand the question. I thought you wanted to render the month in a 2-digit format and year of a given date. In the `en-US` locale this would be in the format MM/YYYY. If this is not your goal, then what are you trying to achieve?